# Bootstrap data-spy doesn't make my navbar full size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
    <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">A09hopper.xyz</a>
     </div>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
     </ul>
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron" style="text-align:center;">
  <h1>Main Page</h1>      
  <p>This is the main page. Just like a contents page.</p>
</div>



<p id="demo"></p>
<div>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
</div>
</body>
```

This is my code. At the top of the page it is full width. When data-spy kicks in it   starts to go to quarer of the size. I have no idea why though?
If this can be solved with CSS please can someone say what needs to be fixed and I will toy around with it until I get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp)

Check the code and fix this.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I used this link but didn't see the top bit and just jumped straight into it.